# How to send a mail with mention?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

When I get mails:

```
GET /beta/me/messages
```

I can check this to see if someone mentioned me.

```
mentionsPreview: {
  isMentioned: true
}
```

How can I send out a mail and mention someone or some people in the mail?

I didn't find any info in the [document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_sendmail).

---

**UPDATE 1:**
I can successfully add mentions when create a new mail and send out by

```
POST /beta/me/sendMail

{
  // ...
  "mentions":[{    
    "mentioned": {
      "name": "Jack",
      "address": "jack@example.com"
     },
    "createdBy": {
      "name": "Me",
      "address": "me@example.com"
    }
  }]
}
```

However, I failed to add mentions when reply a mail. I create a draft first by

```
POST /beta/me/messages/{messageId}/createReplyAll
```

Then I update it by (this step failed to add mentions)

```
PATCH /beta/me/messages/{messageId}

{
  "body": {
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "hi"
  },
  "mentions":[{    
    "mentioned": {
      "name": "Jack",
      "address": "jack@example.com"
     },
    "createdBy": {
      "name": "Me",
      "address": "me@example.com"
    }
  }]
}
```

I send it out by

```
POST /beta/me/messages/{messageId}/send
```

In the mail Jack got, the content successfully updated. But `mentionsPreview` is still null.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks Jason's help.

Further test, I succeed add mention by

```
POST /beta/me/messages/{messageId}/mentions

{
  "mentioned": {
    "address": "jack@example.com"
  }
}
```

But I failed to add mentions using array

```
POST /beta/me/messages/{messageId}/mentions

{
  "mentions":[{    
    "mentioned": {
      "address": "jack@example.com"
    }
  }]
}
```

which means I have to POST mentions one by one at least for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/mention

> When creating a message, an app can create a mention in the same `POST` request by including the mention in the **mentions** property.

**UPDATE**

On your new question about doing this on a reply, the problem is you cannot PATCH in mentions like that. You can only include mentions inline with the rest of the message if you do it at message creation. Since you've already created the message (via the `createReplyAll` method), to update mentions you need to POST new mentions to the `/mentions` relationship on the message, like:

```
POST /me/messages/{messageId}/mentions

{    
  "mentioned": {
    "name": "Jack",
    "address": "jack@example.com"
  },
  "createdBy": {
    "name": "Me",
    "address": "me@example.com"
  }
}
```

As an interesting side note, you CANNOT currently include mentions inline using the `replyAll` method. It seems that you can only do this when creating a brand new message or when sending a new message. For all other cases, you need to do a POST to the `/mentions` relationship as above.

Comment: Hmm, I just found out if I send out a new mail, I can add mentions successfully. But when I reply, I failed to add mentions.

Comment: Works perfect, just add for future people, right now `v1.0` does not support, has to be `/beta`